# how to use the state of a variable for another class in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I wanted to use in props."restaurants".map. What could I do to use this variable in Editar2.js?

---App.js---

```
const { restaurantes } = this.state;
```

---Editar2.js---

```
const EscolheRestaurante = (props) => {
    
    const opcoes = props.restaurantes.map((opcao) => {
        return(<option key={opcao.idRestaurante} value={opcao.idRestaurante}>{opcao.nomeRestaurante}</option>)  
    })

    return (
        <select required className="form-select" onChange={props.idRestauranteEscolhido}>
            <option value="">Escolha um restaurante</option>
            {opcoes}
        </select>
    )
}
```

Comment: are `Edit2` and `Editar2` different ?

Comment: You have to pass it into Edit2.js as a prop, <Edit2 restaurantes={this.state.restaurantes} />

Comment: @KavinduVIndika No srry

Comment: @windmaomao but editar2.js is not defined in App.js

Answer (score 0):

```
<select required className="form-select" onChange={props.idRestauranteEscolhido}>
        <option value="">Escolha um restaurante</option>
        {
            props.restaurantes.map((opcao) => {
                return(
        <option key={opcao.idRestaurante} value={opcao.idRestaurante}>
            {opcao.nomeRestaurante}
        </option>
                ) 
    })
    }
```